# SSRS Expression to change row color on click

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an expression that works when I click a row, the colour changes the row I've clicked on when the report is reloaded and retunes results.

```
=IIf(Parameters!col1.Value = Fields!col1.Value 
AND Parameters!col2.Value = Fields!col2.Value, "#f1cbff", "White")
```

However when I apply the same expression with an extra clause the colour doesn't change.

```
=IIf(Parameters!col1.Value = Fields!col1.Value AND
 Parameters!col2.Value = Fields!col2.Value AND
 Parameters!col3.Value = Fields!col3.Value, "#f1cbff", "White")
```

Comment: expression seems correct, need to verify all these 3 clause outside to check weather conditions are applying or not.

Comment: Would it work if I used a SWITCH statement?

Comment: It doesn't work with a SWITCH statement and I guess why would it?

Comment: `=IIf(Parameters!col3.Value = Fields!col3.Value 
, "#f1cbff", "White")` try this expression only and let us know is it working. I mean check row color

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work?

Comment: So it must be issue with this clause. Either `Parameters!col3.Value` or `Fields!col3.Value` values are different. Please check it dear.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters!col3.Value never equals Fields!col3.Value.

Comment: Parameters!col3.Value never equals Fields!col3.Value - Why it cannot be same?

Comment: It used to work, and since that condition was added it does not work therefore it is that condition that does not work....

Comment: I've got a main report that passes parameters to a subreport and the subreport passes more parameters to another subreport, however in the main report I've set the action to point back to the main report and pass back parameters needed for the main report and the subreports as I''ve added two subreport items to the main report and pointed them at the subreports.

Comment: The first expression works when clicking on a row from the main report and the report reloads and the first subreport becomes visible and the row clicked on in the tablix in the main report is highlighted with the colour defined in the expression, this does not seem to work when going form subreport to subreport but fine from parent to subreport.